# How sustainable is replacing a gas car with an electric car, since gas car still exists?

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions, electric-vehicles

I drive a 2010 BMW 535i maybe 100 km/week, mostly urban driving. My wife also has a gasoline car which we can use for longer trips. I want to reduce our greenhouse gas emissions by buying an electric car (Nissan Leaf? Tesla Model 3? I don't know yet) and I would sell my BMW, which is in good working order.

Aren't I just adding to the problem (greenhouse gas emission) because the BMW would still be on the road somewhere else, as well as contributing to the environmental impact of the production of the electric car (not to mention future battery disposal etc)? I would not want to simply park the BMW somewhere forever, or recycle it for parts, as there is still too much value in it.

Should I just maintain my current gas car? Or does it still make sense to buy a battery electric vehicle (BEV)?

Comment: Not sure how my vote was sufficient to get this question closed -- but in any case, does the linked question provide the answers you're looking for? The study in the top-rated answer is from 2006, and presumably EVs have improved since then, so it's possible that answer no longer holds.

Comment: I closed it as duplicate